# Working with computing changes with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compute changes via java programming --> Parallel arrays.
For some reason i keep getting "0s" as my output. But the rest of the program runs fine.

Here is the part of my program where the "computing" occurs.

```
  public int computePopulationChange(int population2010[], int population2000[])
  {      
     populationChange[count] = population2000[count] - population2010[count]; 
     return populationChange[count];
  }//end computePopulationChange

  public double computePercentChange(int population2010[], int population2000[])
  {
     percentChange[count] = ((population2000[count] - population2010[count])/population2000[count]) * 100;  
     return percentChange[count];
  }//end computePercentChange
```

Are there specific steps to take when trying to compute numbers from a data file?
I am not to sure as to what i am missing in the whole program.

Comment: Where does `count` come from? How is it set? How are you calling these methods?

Comment: public void printData()
      {
         int oCount;
         for (oCount = 0; oCount < count; oCount++)
            System.out.println ("\t\t" + (oCount+1) +".\t" + countyNames[oCount] +"\t\t" + population2000[oCount] + "\t\t" + population2010[oCount] + "\t\t" + populationChange + "\t\t" + percentDecimalDigits.format(percentChange[oCount]));
         System.out.println ("\n\t\t Total Number of Data Lines Processed = " + count);
         System.out.println ("\t" +DASHES);

Comment: shoot.. im not to sure where to post it --;;

Comment: You can edit your answer via the "edit" link at its bottom. It would also be helpful to describe what you want each method to do.

Comment: It wont let me add the whole program.

Comment: Generally, the count comes from a data file. It reads the total number of lines in the file.
Per line of data, there are 3 variables. a county name // population 2000 // population 2010.

I read that data into the program, and compute the changes in population.

The provided program above, is supposed to take each population from each line, and compute it.

But for some reason, i keep getting 0's in all of them.

Comment: Okay, so you could either read/compute/report for each line or for the whole file. In the former case, you don't need arrays at all. In the latter case, you're going to need to iterate when you read, when you compute, and when you report.

Answer (score 1):

You're not iterating over your arrays. Consequently, you're not filling the result array.

If the result should be another parallel array, then consider something like this:

```
public int[] computePopulationChange(int population2010[], int population2000[])
{
    int count = population2010.length;
    int[] result = new int[ count ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        result[i] = population2010[i] - population2000[i];
    }

    return result;
}//end computePopulationChange
```

Comment: The count is from the total # of lines of a data file.
I will include my whole program to help clear up the picture.

Comment: could you clarify what the population2010.length does?

Comment: It provides the length of the array. This field is available on every Java array. You could provide the number of elements to consider compute via a different mechanism, but be sure it is less than the length of each of the parallel input arrays.

Comment: When i use this, I have issues when calling the methods into the client file.

Comment: required: int[],int[]
  found: no arguments

 compChange = reportFile.computePopulationChange();
reportFile.columnHeading('o');
         reportFile.printData(compChange[i]);

Comment: Your sample code in the last comment lacks arguments to computePopulationChange(), as noted by the error you mentioned. Also, looking at your sample code for printData, note that you'll need to iterate over the rows when you print the results (which might include input and computed values for each row).